# Setting a node in a specific location Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, scene, pane

I'm trying to make a Scrabble game, but I'm having trouble adding the tiles to match exactly to the board coordinates. SO far I'm having trouble figuring that out. Here is my code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static final int TILE_SIZE = 40;
    private static final int W = 800;
    private static final int H = 600;

    private static final int X_TILES = 15;
    private static final int Y_TILES = 15;

    private Tile[][] grid = new Tile[X_TILES][Y_TILES];
    private GameTile[][] bag = new GameTile[19][19];

    double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
    double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;

    Group tileGroup = new Group();
    Group pieceGroup = new Group();
    private Scene scene;

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        scene = new Scene(createContent());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    private Parent createContent() {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(W, H);
        root.getChildren().addAll(tileGroup, pieceGroup);

        //creates board tiles
        for (int x = 0; x < X_TILES; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < Y_TILES; y++) {
                Tile tile = new Tile(x, y);
                grid[y][x] = tile;
                tileGroup.getChildren().add(tile);
            }
        }

        int z = 0;

        //creates bag tiles
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            for (int x = 15; x < 18; x++) {
                GameTile bagTile = new GameTile(x, y);
                bagTile.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

                bagTile.setOnMousePressed(e -> {

                    orgSceneX = e.getSceneX();
                    orgSceneY = e.getSceneY();
                    orgTranslateX = ((GameTile) (e.getSource())).getTranslateX();
                    orgTranslateY = ((GameTile) (e.getSource())).getTranslateY();


                });

                bagTile.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                    double offsetX = e.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
                    double offsetY = e.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
                    double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
                    double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;



                    ((GameTile) (e.getSource())).setTranslateX((int)(newTranslateX));
                    ((GameTile) (e.getSource())).setTranslateY((int)newTranslateY);
                });
                bagTile.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {


                });

                bag[x][y] = bagTile;
                root.getChildren().add(bagTile);
                z++;
            }
        }

        return root;
    }


}
```

I tried implementing a mouse handler, but so far I keep failing to understand how to make the exact coordinates match the board underneath the draggable tiles.

Comment: Have you considered using a `GridPane` with click-to-select and click-to-place tiles?Would be easier to devleop *and* I feel that if I were playing scrabble I'd rather click than keep dragging my tiles into place anyways.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709178/how-to-drag-and-drop-button-onto-gridpane/55709991#55709991

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use ideas from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709178/how-to-drag-and-drop-button-onto-gridpane/55709991#55709991) answer. I altered the code so that it sets the node that is being dragged invisible and shows a snapshot of that node being dragged by the mouse.

You could probably use `Label` instead of `Button` for the `Tiles`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demonstrates a drag-and-drop feature.
 */
public class App extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        //Source Buttons.
        final Button boat1 = new Button("boat1");
        final Button boat2 = new Button("boat2");
        final Button boat3 = new Button("boat3");
        final Button boat4 = new Button("boat4");

        //Adding OnDragDetected to source Buttons.
        setOnDragDetected(boat1);
        setOnDragDetected(boat2);
        setOnDragDetected(boat3);
        setOnDragDetected(boat4);

        //Adding onDragDone to source Buttons.
        setOnDragDone(boat1);
        setOnDragDone(boat2);
        setOnDragDone(boat3);
        setOnDragDone(boat4);

        //Creating GridPane
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setVgap(5);
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        //Adding StackPane to every Cell in the GridPane and Adding the Target Events to each StackPane.
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
            stackPane.setPrefSize(150, 50);
            stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
            setOnDragOver(stackPane);
            setOnDragEntered(stackPane);
            setOnDragExited(stackPane);
            setOnDragDropped(stackPane);

            gridPane.add(stackPane, i / 3, i % 3);
        }

        HBox root = new HBox(new VBox(boat1, boat2, boat3, boat4), gridPane);
        stage.setTitle("Hello Drag And Drop");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    //source events handlers
    public void setOnDragDetected(Button source)
    {
        source.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
            /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture*/
            System.out.println("onDragDetected");

            /* allow any transfer mode */
            Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);            
            db.setDragView(source.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null));
            source.setVisible(false);
            /* put a string on dragboard */
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(source.getText());
            db.setContent(content);

            event.consume();
        });
    }

    public void setOnDragDone(Button source)
    {
        source.setOnDragDone((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* the drag-and-drop gesture ended */
            System.out.println("onDragDone");
            /* if the data was successfully moved, clear it */
//            if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
//                source.setText("");
//            }

            event.consume();
        });
    }

    //target event handlers
    public void setOnDragOver(StackPane target)
    {
        target.setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* data is dragged over the target */
            System.out.println("onDragOver");

            /* accept it only if it is  not dragged from the same node
            * and if it has a string data */
            if (event.getGestureSource() != target
                    && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }

            event.consume();
        });
    }

    public void setOnDragEntered(StackPane target)
    {
        target.setOnDragEntered((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* the drag-and-drop gesture entered the target */
            System.out.println("onDragEntered");
            /* show to the user that it is an actual gesture target */
            if (event.getGestureSource() != target
                    && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                target.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
            }

            event.consume();
        });
    }

    public void setOnDragExited(StackPane target)
    {
        target.setOnDragExited((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* mouse moved away, remove the graphical cues */
            target.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");

            event.consume();
        });
    }

    public void setOnDragDropped(StackPane target)
    {
        target.setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* data dropped */
            System.out.println("onDragDropped");
            /* if there is a string data on dragboard, read it and use it */
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasString()) {
                //target.setText(db.getString());
                Button tempBoat = new Button(db.getString());
                tempBoat.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
                target.getChildren().clear();
                target.getChildren().add(tempBoat);
                success = true;
            }
            /* let the source know whether the string was successfully
            * transferred and used */
            event.setDropCompleted(success);

            event.consume();
        });
    }    
}
```

[image]